# Heroku JVM tuning

Tags: java, scala, heroku, jvm

I've written an application on Play2 framework for Heroku and am having memory issues.

```
2013-03-21T01:28:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=543M(106.1%)
2013-03-21T01:28:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Locally I've profiled it with the same JVM settings and memory restrictions on Heroku (512MB) but almost instantly when I send requests at Heroku it runs our of heap space.

```
JAVA_OPTS:    -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

I wouldn't have any issues if I could profile what's going on there, but the java-agent doest seem to work for me.

I havent come across any memory leaks that I've seen. I do know that every object I create is and will only be used once so I could make my young gen large and my old gen small. I've tried different JVM values but can't seem to find the right combination to get this working without the correct profiling.

I've read all the Heroku docs on tuning and such with no avail. Does anyone have any ideas on this, or maybe point me in the right direction?

### EDIT

I still have not been able to get remote monitoring working, but here is some dumps from my local test system before and after 1 full CG.

```
{Heap before GC invocations=1747 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 42496K, used 42496K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fded0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 42176K, 100% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f7e90000,0x00000000f7e90000)
  from space 320K, 100% used [0x00000000fde80000,0x00000000fded0000,0x00000000fded0000)
  to   space 640K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd90000,0x00000000fdd90000,0x00000000fde30000)
 PSOldGen        total 106176K, used 105985K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e67b0000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 106176K, 99% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e67804c8,0x00000000e67b0000)
 PSPermGen       total 43712K, used 43684K [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000d84b0000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 43712K, 99% used [0x00000000d5a00000,0x00000000d84a9338,0x00000000d84b0000)
2013-03-21T14:09:36.827-0700: [GC [PSYoungGen: 42496K->384K(41536K)] 148481K->106450K(147712K), 0.0027940 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=1747 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 41536K, used 384K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fde90000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 41152K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f7d90000)
  from space 384K, 100% used [0x00000000fdd90000,0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fddf0000)
  to   space 640K, 0% used [0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fde90000)
 PSOldGen        total 106176K, used 106066K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e67b0000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 106176K, 99% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e6794968,0x00000000e67b0000)
 PSPermGen       total 43712K, used 43684K [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000d84b0000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 43712K, 99% used [0x00000000d5a00000,0x00000000d84a9338,0x00000000d84b0000)
}
{Heap before GC invocations=1748 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 41536K, used 384K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fde90000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 41152K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f7d90000)
  from space 384K, 100% used [0x00000000fdd90000,0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fddf0000)
  to   space 640K, 0% used [0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fde90000)
 PSOldGen        total 106176K, used 106066K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e67b0000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 106176K, 99% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e6794968,0x00000000e67b0000)
 PSPermGen       total 43712K, used 43684K [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000d84b0000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 43712K, 99% used [0x00000000d5a00000,0x00000000d84a9338,0x00000000d84b0000)
2013-03-21T14:09:36.830-0700: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 384K->0K(41536K)] [PSOldGen: 106066K->13137K(52224K)] 106450K->13137K(93760K) [PSPermGen: 43684K->43684K(87936K)], 0.0666250 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.07 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=1748 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 41536K, used 0K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fde90000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 41152K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f7d90000)
  from space 384K, 0% used [0x00000000fdd90000,0x00000000fdd90000,0x00000000fddf0000)
  to   space 640K, 0% used [0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fddf0000,0x00000000fde90000)
 PSOldGen        total 52224K, used 13137K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e3300000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 52224K, 25% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0cd4528,0x00000000e3300000)
 PSPermGen       total 87936K, used 43684K [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000dafe0000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 87936K, 49% used [0x00000000d5a00000,0x00000000d84a9338,0x00000000dafe0000)
}
```

### EDIT

This is what I can get -- which isnt much, but this is what happens after 100 requests as everything starts to degrade, you can see web.2 already swapped in this dump

```
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=load_avg_1m val=0.41
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=memory_total val=246.95 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=memory_rss val=246.91 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=memory_cache val=0.05 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=memory_swap val=0.00 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=memory_pgpgin val=72259 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=heroku.13369226.web.1.d615093e-77a3-42b1-8da1-a228bd7582a1 measure=memory_pgpgout val=9039 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=load_avg_1m val=0.30
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=memory_total val=532.83 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=memory_rss val=511.86 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=memory_cache val=0.04 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=memory_swap val=20.93 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=memory_pgpgin val=145460 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=heroku.13369226.web.2.cb423d08-dd15-41c1-9843-95bcdc269111 measure=memory_pgpgout val=14414 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process running mem=532M(104.1%)
2013-03-21T22:24:25+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=load_avg_1m val=1.83
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=memory_total val=400.66 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=memory_rss val=400.61 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=memory_cache val=0.05 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=memory_swap val=0.00 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=memory_pgpgin val=113336 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.4]: source=heroku.13369226.web.4.25274242-a3af-4d2e-9da3-44e5e0a45c09 measure=memory_pgpgout val=10767 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=load_avg_1m val=0.25
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=memory_total val=397.70 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=memory_rss val=397.64 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=memory_cache val=0.05 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=memory_swap val=0.00 units=MB
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=memory_pgpgin val=112163 units=pages
2013-03-21T22:24:29+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=heroku.13369226.web.3.2132f01f-94b1-4151-8fa8-09cdb2774919 measure=memory_pgpgout val=10353 units=pages
```

Comment: Can you set -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and collect the file for analysis?  Are you actually getting an OOM or just violating some sort of policy?

Comment: It's actually violating a restriction on memory usage as seen in the heroku output.

Comment: you can't connect to your deployed app via jmx or any other means?

Comment: No -- there is a "router" that blocks any other incoming connections other than port 80. That's what makes this so hard to debug, There is a simple java agent I found that dumps some memory values into the logs but I have been unable to get it to work. I am going o spend another hour or so on this and update here my finding.

Comment: Did your resolve the issue? We are having the same problem.

We fixed the memory options to use java_opts in lower case so that the options get passed to the java command as @WearyMonkey correctly points out this is required with the start script.

Thought that would have fixed it, but no. We're logging JVM memory usage and the JVM is not (apparently) using the memory, yet we still get R14 errors after some period of time when we run a stress test.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Heroku is telling you the machine is running out of memory, not the Java VM. There is actually a bug in the Heroku Play 2.2 deployment, the startup script reads java_opts, not JAVA_OPTS.

I fixed it by setting both:

```
heroku config:add java_opts='-Xmx384m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops'
heroku config:add JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx384m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops'
```

I also had to set -Xms otherwise I got an error saying the min and max were incompatible. I guess Play2.2 was using a default higher than 384m.

To find out your total memory used, [this is a useful equation](https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx) (pre java 8):

`Max memory = [-Xmx] + [-XX:MaxPermSize] + number_of_threads * [-Xss]`

Comment: So, the real answer is if you aren't getting `OutOfMemoryError`s in the logs, then it is Heroku complaining and not your VM?  And adjusting your VM's settings will make Heroku stop complaining (and swapping your app to disk)?

Comment: Yes `R14` errors mean the dyno is running out of memory, which usually means you allocated too much to the JVM.

Comment: It means that the app/dyno is being swapped to disk, running out of memory according to heroku.  But not according to the JVM (which is why you have to specify the heapsize arguments).  I believe this is correct.

Comment: See my answer for *why* he exceeded that memory limit; er, because I've had this exact issue with other memory-limited systems (in my case, AWS t2.nano hosts).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 diagnostic tools in this Heroku devcenter article that may be helpful:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues

Have a look at the memory logging agent, verbose GC flags, and log-runtime-metrics(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics). Those should give you some more visibility.

Comment: I've read this document and use VirtualVM for my local logging, this does not work for Heroku. I've also used the heroku-agent which does not dump the memory data as stated above. Also the Java standard memory dump attributes do not display any data either on the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to factor in the Permgen (pre-JRE 8) or [Metaspace](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace) (JRE-8+) memory needs; this is the memory reserved for Java class information and certain static information.  Plan on it being another 100-150MB on top of heap, looks like yours is higher.  You can cap it with the -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize flag, but be aware that if you exceed that limit you'll get errors.

I have a server also capped at -Xmx384M, and it turns out that real memory use is also around 500 MB (but would go higher with more complex applications) with Metaspace factored in. It's running a fairly complex app (Jenkins), so the Metaspace size ends up being about 170 MB, of it the heap hits its limits, 554 MB of RAM used.